# Change output with restrictions

Tags: java, function, class

In this program the output is:

```
70,60
30,40
```

But I want it to be:

```
30,40
70,60
```

And the condition is:

> Do not use `static`, `final`, `this` (or others keywords).
>   And the order of calling the method must remain the same and the signature of methods can't be changed.

Here is the code :

```
class Hello {
    int a = 30, b = 40;

    public void input(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello o = new Hello();

        o.input(70,60);
        o.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: So... Change the program. Swap 70 and 30; 60 and 40. No extra keywords needed.

Comment: You should not change the question once people start answering, in a way that invalidates their answers.  It's not fair on the people who have spent their time helping you.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the exact restrictions. You could just type `o.input(30, 40);` and `int a = 70, b = 60;`. Not allowed? Then, what exactly is allowed? Can the `input` method be adjusted to print `this.a` and `this.b` and then saving `this.a = a;` and `this.b = b;`?

Comment: ok @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: @Zabuza we cannot use **this** keyword!

Comment: You need to be more precise on what exactly is allowed or expected. People gave a lot of good solutions now and you keep saying that it's not what you want. The site is not meant for a forth and back discussion. Ask a precise unambiguous question and then receive a precise answer ([ask]).

Comment: Aside from anything else, this code does not give the output you describe - there is nothing that prints the commas.

Comment: Sorry my mistake ignore the commas please
you can assume it to :
30
40
60
70

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're calling the methods in the wrong order:

```
o.show();
o.input(70,60);
```

Comment: i added few conditions please have look!

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the order of calling the function:-

Instead of this:

```
 public static void main(String...s)
        {
          Hello o=new Hello();
          o.input(70,60);
          o.show();
         }
```

Change

```
 public static void main(String...s)
            {
              Hello o=new Hello();
              o.show();
              o.input(70,60);
             }
```

Or

If you don't wanna change the order then call the function like this:-

```
class Hello {
    int a = 30, b = 40;

    public void input(int a, int b) {
        show();
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello o = new Hello();

        o.input(70,60);
        //o.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i added few conditions please have look!

Comment: @PiyushArora check the answer.

Comment: we can't put comment in front of show(). the order of execution must be same in main method.

Comment: You don't want to change the code or anything? That makes no sense. Too get the expected output.

Comment: may be you don't wanna get the output??

Comment: I wanna get it and I will get it...thanks for your precious time .

Comment: It's not possible without changing the program. you will able to get it by doing some changes.

Comment: but you just said that there is no changes allowed in function and order of execution of function.

Answer (score 1):

Swap `o.input(70,60)` and `o.show()` statements.

```
public static void main(String...s)
    {
      Hello o=new Hello();
      o.show();
      o.input(70,60);
     }
```

Comment: i added few conditions please have look!

Answer (score 1):

### Hardcoded numbers

Change the hardcoded numbers:

```
int a = 70, b = 60;
...
o.input(30, 40);
```

---

### Method order

Or change the method order:

```
o.show();
o.input(70, 60);
```

---

### Adjust `input`

You can also adjust the `input` method to output the member variables instead of the arguments and afterwards update the members with the arguments so that `show` will print the updated members:

```
public void input(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println(this.a);
    System.out.println(this.b);

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

---

### Hardcoded math

Similarly you could use math to achieve the same without `this`:

```
public void input(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println(a - 40);
    System.out.println(b - 20);
}

public void show() {
    System.out.println(a + 40);
    System.out.println(b + 20);
}
```

Comment: @PiyushArora You don't want to change the code? That makes no sense. How should the output change if you don't change anything?

Comment: @Zabuza Right.!!